# Combining subversion history after moving one file on top of another?

Tags: svn, merge

In a subversion repository, there is a binary file (MS Word document) with a long history of changes. Recently, the file was modified by the following problematic operations, losing the history. First, a copy was made and committed to the repository:

```
$ cp original.docx copy.docx
$ svn add copy.docx
$ svn commit
```

Next, the copy was edited and committed many times. (original.docx was never modified again.)

Finally, the original file was replaced by the copy using "svn mv":

```
$ svn mv original.docx oldjunk.docx
$ svn mv copy.docx original.docx
$ svn commit
```

This is bad because much of the history of "original.docx" is no longer found by "svn log original.docx" -- the history is in "oldjunk.docx".

The author intends to "svn rm oldjunk.docx" in the future, which would lose all that history. What is the best sequence of subversion operations that would permit the command:

```
$ svn log original.docx
```

to show the *appended* history of (what is now called) original.docx and oldjunk.docx?

Remember these are binary files so we can't arbitrarily merge content.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. `svn log original.docx` *now* must show history of copy.docx **and** original.docx 
   (due to correct rename)
2. Even deleted from repository file still stored in history and this history can be extracted from repository (read about PEG-revisions): i.e. if `oldjunk.docx` will be removed in $REVISION (you can find this revision from `svn log -v`), for `$N = $REVISION - 1` in `svn log oldjunk.docx@K` you will be able to get history of original.docx + oldjunk.docx

You can (theoretically) with a lot of tricks and black magic rewrite history in repository and replace `cp original.docx copy.docx` by correct revision with nice change, but:

- It will require big hard accurate work
- It require administrative level of access to repository and repository-server (intermediate repository have to be created in process)